# Reading a file into a struct

Tags: c

I'm working my way through the learn c the hard way [book](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/) and have run into a few issues on Exercise 17. In the example code we create a custom database and write it to a file. We then read it back again in order to edit it.

```
struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode)
{
    struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
    if (!conn) die("Memory error");

    conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
    if (!conn->db) die("Memory error");

    if (mode == 'c') {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "w");
    }
    else {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+");
        if (conn->file) {
            Database_load(conn);
        }
    }

    if (!conn->file) die("Failed to open the file");

    return conn;
}
```

It appears I can create the database ok (in mode 'c') but when I go back to try and read it

```
void Database_load(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int rc = fread(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
    if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load database.");
}
```

`rc` is always 0.

I have tried lots of experiments reading a writing files and the closest I've come to getting it to work is to read the file as binary i.e.

```
    else {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "rb+");
```

That causes rc to not be 0 however it seems to corrupt other parts of the program.

Does anyone else have any thing else I could try? The only other thing I need to mention is I am building on Visual Studio 2013 and the example code is intended for gcc, should this make a difference?

I've only included the source I think is relevant but the [full code is here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html) if it aids in answering.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to write with mode `"wb"` and read with `"rb+"`?

Comment: @lightness-races-in-orbit sorry typo - fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted, the fact your code is intended for gcc doesn't matter. 
It may be an error in your file, is it a text file or a binary file ? In the last case, you can explore it with utilities as HxD.

Good luck

Comment: If you write a full structure into a file it's in binary mode, but if there were some dynamically allocated elements in the struct you wrote, you'll need an index table or something like that

Comment: I'm really not sure, if you write a struct like Database to a file should it be binary or text? When I write is as in text mode it still appears to look like binary inside the file:
 
    struct Address {
     int id;
     int set;
     char name[MAX_DATA];
     char email[MAX_DATA];
    };
    
    struct Database {
     struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
    };

Comment: So if you're writing a struct to a file and you've open the file in non-binary mode, this could cause problems?

Comment: Yes, a structure is a group of binary data.